# Default value for function inputs - Not allowing use of one input to define another

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to define a function with a lot of input variables, and some of the inputs are used to define other input variables. If I define them outside of the function and then pass them in I don't get an issue, but if I do the following then I get an issue

```
SolveSEIRs[n_: 500,
L_: RandomReal[{3.9,5.9}],
Cinc_: RandomReal[{Max[L,4.8],6.8}],
etc...
```

The error message that I am getting states...

> "RandomReal: The endpoints specified by {Max[4.8,L],6.8} for the endpoints 
> of the uniform distribution range are not real-valued"

I have tried to look online for solutions to this problem, but I feel as though this might be a slightly specific issue, or that I am unable to describe it effectively due to being new to Mathematica.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with polymorphic definitions:

```
SolveSEIRs[] := SolveSEIRs[500];
SolveSEIRs[n_] := SolveSEIRs[n, RandomReal[{3.9, 5.9}]];
SolveSEIRs[n_, L_] := SolveSEIRs[n, L, RandomReal[{Max[L, 4.8], 6.8}]];
SolveSEIRs[n_, L_, Cinc_] := WhateverHappensHere[n, L, Cinc];
```

**COMMENT**

This might be too tangential, but my general advice is to avoid the default argument value syntax altogether. It can make for complications both in understanding your functions and also in how the evaluator actually interprets those defaults. Polymorphic definitions (as I showed) and using options are both preferable, in my estimation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - so does this mean that for 13 input variables I would need to define 14 of these functions? Also, this situation occurs three times again where I am using an input variable in a RandomReal function to define another input variable, does that affect how I would use this method to create my function?

Comment: not necessarily. It depends on the details and the semantics of your arguments.

Comment: This seems to me to be very strange design. I can't provide feedback without knowing your context, but just specifying the default value to be random is itself kind of weird. On top of that, creating these dependencies between arguments is just fraught. My gut tells me there's a better way of going about this altogether.